# How to get generated content in Apache module and save it to file

Tags: c, apache

I have been playing around with Apache module development and got the module working. However, I ran into the issue of where to hook properly to get all the data I need.

I am making a simple caching module that needs to hook at the beginning of the request and check if the file for this URL exists on disk and if it does then serve that file and stop content generation of Apache.

Currently, the module still continues to go into content generation mode. Let's say I have a long-running PHP script that takes 5s to generate. I would to omit calling the script altogether and just serve the static file from disk.

Furthermore, if the local file does not exist, I would like Apache to execute content generation (actually executes the PHP script) and before sending that data to the client I would like to have a proper hook that somehow gets this data and saves it to a local file.

I have tried `ap_hook_fixups`, `ap_hook_handler` and `APR_HOOK_LAST`, `APR_HOOK_LAST` and all the variations but no luck.

It always executes at the start of the request.

I also do not want to use any existing Apache modules. I want this to be a self-contained module.

Is there a way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have provided, it sounds like you want your module to execute First and not last.

From what I understand of your issue, you want to make sure the file that would potentially be generated is already on disk or not, and if it is, serve that file, instead of allowing your php script to serve it.

In this case, you'll want to use `APR_HOOK_FIRST` or `APR_HOOK_REALLY_FIRST`
Then, assuming your file is on disk, you serve your file, and at the end of your module's work do a `return OK;`

If the file does not exist, do a `return DECLINED`

The `DECLINED` tells Apache that your module should not be the handler for this request and will continue down the list of modules till it finds something that will.
The goal here is to get your module to run before the php module does, to prevent your generation code from running, and fall back onto the php module if the requested file was not found.

Note:
The `APR_HOOK_?` [priorities are just numbers](https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/trunk/group___a_p_r___util___hook.html) -10 to 30

You should be able to fine tune this if you find your module executing a little too soon, like before mod_ssl for example.

Also, I am terrible at following documents, but the official [Apache module development docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html) are amazingly assembled. Please try to use them, if you have,

I have spent the last 6 months messing around with Apache module development, working on a telegram bot.
I have had to do this song and dace a few times now.